# I have updated my private podfile and incremented version number. When i'm trying to update pod file it's giving error

Tags: ios, swift, github, cocoapods

[).13.9 is version number we incremented. When i'm trying to update it's not updating. it's giving error. We're maintaining all pod specs in one repo. What ever the updated internal versions we added to that repo.

[image: PF Image Here]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update and push the tags associated with the new version.